# Jqgrid - Table not displaying responsive behavior

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Hi I Have the following code which displays the table using jqgrid. But, i noticed 
that none of the jqGrid is being responsive.

How can i make existing jqGrid responsive for tablet and smart phones

**UPUDATE**

I have updated my code with the following

```
 $(window).on("resize", function () {
    var newWidth = $("#loanGrid").closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
   $("#loanGrid").jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
});
```

The respomnsiveness works but not completely.

Here is the code below and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/w7pxts0z/3/) here 
HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-11">
         <h3 class="subheader"> Sample Info </h4>
         <div class="redmond">
            <table id="output"></table>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>     
</div>
```

jqGrid JavaScript

```
$("#output").jqGrid({
    url: jsonData,
    mtype: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    /*  postData: {
          json: JSON.stringify(data)
      },
      */
    colModel: [
      /**    { name: 'ClientID', label:'ClientID',width: 80, key: true },****/
      {
        name: 'Symbol',
        label: 'Symbol',
        align: 'left',
        width: 65
      }, {
        name: 'Description',
        label: 'Description',
        align: 'left',
        width: 165
      }, {
        name: 'ShareQuantity',
        label: 'ShareQuantity',
        align: 'right',
        width: "85",
        formatter: 'currency',
        formatoptions: {
          prefix: " ",
          suffix: " "
        }
      }, {
        name: 'SharePrice',
        label: 'Share Price',
        align: 'right',
        width: 100,
        template: "number",
        formatoptions: {
          prefix: " $",
          decimalPlaces: 4
        }
      },
      /*{ label: 'Value1', 
                  name: 'Value1', 
                  width: 80, 
                  sorttype: 'number', 
                  formatter: 'number',
                  align: 'right'
              }, */
      {
        name: 'TotalValue',
        label: 'Total Value',
        width: 160,
        sorttype: 'number',
        align: "right",
        formatter: 'currency',
        formatoptions: {
          prefix: " $",
          suffix: " "
        }
      }, {
        name: 'LTVRatio',
        label: 'LTV Ratio',
        width: 70,
        sorttype: 'number',
        align: "right",
        formatter: 'percentage',
        formatoptions: {
          prefix: " ",
          suffix: " "
        }
      }, {
        name: 'LTVCategory',
        label: 'LTV Category',
        width: 120,
        width: 165
      },

      {
        name: 'MaxLoanAmt',
        label: 'MaxLoanAmount',
        width: 165,
        sorttype: 'number',
        align: "right",
        formatter: 'currency',
        formatoptions: {
          prefix: " $",
          suffix: " "
        }
      }

    ],
    additionalProperties: ["Num1"],
    /*beforeProcessing: function (data) {
        var item, i, n = data.length;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            item = data[i];
            item.Quantity = parseFloat($.trim(item.Quantity).replace(",", ""));
            item.LTVRatio = parseFloat($.trim(item.LTVRatio *10000).replace(",", ""));
            item.Value = parseFloat($.trim(item.Value).replace(",", ""));
            item.Num1 = parseInt($.trim(item.Num1).replace(",", ""), 10);
            item.Num2 = parseInt($.trim(item.Num2).replace(",", ""), 10);
        }
    }, */
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    loadonce: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    cmTemplate: {
      autoResizable: true,
      editable: true
    },
    autoResizing: {
      compact: true
    },
    forceClientSorting: true,
    sortname: "Symbol",
    footerrow: true,
    caption: "<b>Collateral Value</b> <span class='pull-right' style='margin-right:20px;'>Valuation as of: " + mmddyyyy + "</span>",


    loadComplete: function() {
      var $self = $(this),
        sum = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "Price", false, "sum"),
        sum1 = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "MaxLoanAmt", false, "sum");
      //ltvratio =  $self.jqGrid("getCol","LTVRatio:addas", "Aved Loan Amount");
      $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {
        LTVCategory: "Max Approved Loan Amount:",
        Price: sum,
        MaxLoanAmt: sum1
      });
    }
  });

  //jQuery("#loanGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true,  searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
});
```

Comment: You need include the code, which resize the grid (something like `$(window).bind("resize", ...)`). See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/45/ or http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/46/ and [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35505598/315935), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34226305/315935), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25036623/315935) and some other

Comment: @Oleg- Thank you . I added the following code as per example and it is now responsive, but not completely. The responsiveness breaks down for example after the screen size reached 778px.   How can I make it work? what ami missing? I followed your examplehttp://jsfiddle.net/ejpn9/4/ and this is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/w7pxts0z/3/

Comment: Why you post all time the demos, which are not working? You can just modify my demos and include your code and data to have working demos. If you need to load the data from `url` then you can use [Echo](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html#json) service of jsfiddle: you need just use `url: '/echo/json/'` and send JSON data as `json` parameter. In case of jqGrid it means the usage of `url: '/echo/json/', mtype: "POST", datatype: "json", postData: { json: JSON.stringify(jsonData) }`. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/w7pxts0z/5/ What exactly you want to fix?

Comment: You should describe **which responsive behavior** you need to implement on resizing. One can for example resize all columns, one can resize one specific column or one can hide some columns if the grid size (the size of outer container) will be less then some value. You can for example add `classes: "hidden-xs", labelClasses: "hidden-xs"` in some columns to hide the column on width<768px : https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/w7pxts0z/6/ See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) other classes which you can use

Comment: @Oleg - Thank you .  I was trying to resize all the collumns

Comment: If you don't want to hide some columns then I don't understand the problem which you have. You just wrote "The respomnsiveness works but not completely." You should specify exactly what you need to implement and what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap classes `.visible-*` or `hidden-*` to hide/show some elements on the page depend on the window resolution (see [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)). The properties `classes`, `labelClasses` or `colModel` can be used in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (starting with version 4.8, see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README48.md#the-following-new-colmodel-properties-are-implemented-comparing-with-jqgrid-47) and [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/alignLabel.htm)) to assign the classes to the column. For example the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/w7pxts0z/7/ uses

```
classes: "hidden-xs hidden-sm", labelClasses: "hidden-xs hidden-sm"
```

in `LTVCategory` column and the properties

```
classes: "hidden-xs", labelClasses: "hidden-xs"
```

in `ShareQuantity` and `SharePrice` columns. As the result the column `LTVCategory` will be hidden on "extra small devices" (width<768px) and "small devices" (width<992px, but width>=768px).

Comment: Thank u much as always you are very detailed and descriptive . I was able to make it responsive for most part even after following ur example word for word.., the responsive part seemed to not work forbelow 700 px. But the same code work perfectly in JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/w7pxts0z/18/  but not on my machine.. Also , si there a way to pass json data "Name" to caption. example     caption: "<b>Collateral Value</b> <span class='pull-right' style='margin-right:20px;'>Valuation as of: " + Name+ "</span>",

Comment: @user244394: You are welcome! Why you post always non-working jsfiddle demos? The last one have syntax error: missing comma at the end of the line 93 after `labelClasses: "hidden-sm"` before `template: "number",`. The fixed one is https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/w7pxts0z/19/. To add `Name` you can use `jsonData.Name`: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/w7pxts0z/20/. You can change `caption` dynamically using `setCaption` method alternatively.

Comment: I just posted working version of my code, I am using live web services to populate the table in real life vs the fiddle canned data. Thanks to you its working except 2 things , inside caption when i pass jsonData.clientId i am getting undefined and for percentage not showing %  formatter: 'percentage',  https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/w7pxts0z/34/
        formatoptions: {
          prefix: " ",
          suffix: " "
        }

Comment: @user244394: `jsonData` has no `borrower` property. You can use for example `jsonData[0].borrower` instead of `jsonData.borrower`, but I'm not sure that it's what you want to display. There are **no** predefined `formatter: 'percentage'`. You want probably use `formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { suffix: " %" }`? See ttps://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/w7pxts0z/35/

Comment: @user244394: The question is still opened. Is your initial problem (responsive behavior of free jqGrid) is solved now?