# Filtering jqGrid by multiple group conditions at client side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have Jqgrid, where i am showing the transaction history of my bookings And i am using custom filtering on that grid.

Now i have two textboxes, one set of checkboxes representing status and another set of checkboxes representing Product type Out side of jqgrid.

1) Date textbox

2) User Name textbox

3) pending checkbox (status checkbox)

4) confirm checkbox (status checkbox)

5) fail checkbox (status checkbox)

6) Shoe (product checkbox)

7) mobile (product checkbox)

My scenario is, we can choose multiple checkboxes for status, multiple checkboxes for product checkboxes and can type in textboxes.

If user selects failed, Confirm checkboxes and Mobile checkbox and types some name in the name textbox.., then the user need to get the
list of Mobile products those are Confirmed or failed and under the keyed user typed in User Name textbox.

Please help me with this JqGrid filtering.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include in all questions about jqGrid the version of jqGrid, which you use (can use) and from which the fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Free jqGrid, which I develop, support `IN` operation in local filtering. Thus one can use [jQuery MultiSelect UI Widget](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) or [select2](https://github.com/select2/select2) to select multiple items (like `status` values) from the list.

Comment: @Oleg, sorry free jqGrid i am using.

Comment: @Oleg, sorry.., I am not able to get the solutions you added. I hope my scenario is different. Please help me with my scenario.

Comment: I have to do my main job. I try to help other in pauses or in my free time. Moreover, stackoverflow is not the lace where you write requirements and somebody implements all there (do full your job). Thus you should always formulate *one step* of your solution, where you have problem as separate question. It's good to post code fragments or demos, which demonstrates your current state. You should remove all unneeded things, which are not related to the current question. Other developers can modify your code or get you some tips. Such **clear questions will have value for other visitors**.

Comment: Sorry for that.. i hope my question was not clear.. I want to ask a simple question like for one group i want to apply OR condition and for another too. Now want to apply AND between those group. How can i perform.

`"{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],
    
"groups":[
{ "groupOp":"OR",
"rules":[
{"field":"status","op":"cn","data":"Confirmed"},{"field":"status","op":"cn","data":"Failed"}]}],
"groups":[
{ "groupOp":"OR",
"rules":[
{"field":"type","op":"cn","data":"Mobile"},{"field":"type","op":"cn","data":"Shoe"}]}]}"`

Comment: Please answer on my question about the version of jqGrid and the fork. Which `datatype` you use in jqGrid? You ask "How can i perform ... filter?". I don't understand what you mean. Do you have problem with UI or you want to construct the filter manually and you don't know how to apply the filter? Is your question about `filterToolbar` or about Searching Dialog? You mean some specific problem, but the text of your question and your comment can be implemented in many ways.

Comment: The example of the filter, which you posted in the comment uses "cn" (Contain) operation and means something like `(status LIKE '*Confirmed*' OR st‌​atus LIKE '*Failed*') AND (type LIKE '*Mobile*' OR type LIKE '*Sho‌​e*')`. Is it really what you need. More natural would be to use `eq` or `in` operation like in `status IN ('Confirmed', 'Failed') AND (type IN ('Mobile', 'Sho‌​e')`. Many things would be clear it you post the definition of `status` and `type` columns and an example of data. I repeat that the best would be the demo, which demonstrates, what you do.

Comment: I know many questions, where I find out only after 5-10 comments that somebody uses XML instead of JSON as the input or that one uses TreeGrid, Subgrids or Grouped data or multiple grids on the same page without the usage of (`idPrefix`). I can continue... The problem is that many developer uses jqGrid in some *specific way*, but they not describe it because they use jqGrid only in the way. One can spend a lot of time guessing what one need. Many such problems would be solved in minutes if the demo would exist or at least the JavaScript code with test input data would be posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Oleg for your help.  
`"{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[], "groups":[ {"groupOp":"OR", "rules":[ {"field":"status","op":"cn","data":"Confirmed"},{"field":"st‌​atus","op":"cn","dat‌​a":"Failed"}},{{ "groupOp":"OR", "rules":[ {"field":"type","op":"cn","data":"Mobile"},{"field":"type","‌​op":"cn","data":"Sho‌​e"}}] `  
this has solved my scenario.

Comment: I explicitly included in above comment `LIKE` with `'*'` to stress that the usage of `"cn"` is wrong. One should use `"eq"`, or better, `"in"` operation. The resulting filter will be `{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"status","op":"in","data":"Confirmed,Failed"},{"field":"type","op":"in","data":"Mobile,S‌​ho‌​e"}]}`. One can use `inFilterSeparator` option to change the default `,` separator in `IN` operation to another one. See [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/290) for more details.